# Binding button state (isEnabled) with array state in NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to bind the state of a button (isEnabled) to the state of an array (empty/not empty) in the NSUserDefaults.

I might need a NSValueTransformer mapping an empty array to NO and an array with at least an object to YES.

This is not correct, but near:

```
    [showEmptyFolders bind:@"enabled" toObject:[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] withKeyPath:@"kPreferencesFolderArray" options:nil];
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a value transformer that takes an array and returns YES or NO whether it has a non-zero element count or not. Something like this:

```
@interface PositiveCountTransformer : NSValueTransformer 
@end

@implementation PositiveCountTransformer

+ (Class)transformedValueClass
{
    return [NSNumber class];
}

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation
{
    return NO;
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value
{
    NSInteger result;
    if ( [value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] )
        result = [value count];
    else
        result = 0; // Or however you want to handle it

    return [NSNumber numberWithBool:(result > 0)];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 7):

Link the array with an array controller and bind button's `Enabled` binding to `arrangedObjects.@count` keypath. Zero count works as boolean `NO` and any non-zero value is treated as `YES`. (It may work without array controller too, I just didn't try it).

BTW, you can add NSNegateBoolean standard transformer if you need it the opposite way.